# Can I use Spec to build user interfaces in Seaside?

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, specifications, seaside

I have noted in the examples package 'Spec-Examples-PolyWidgets' that is possible to build user interfaces using Polymorph. Could do the same for the Seaside web framework?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually one of the goal of Spec to use multiple framework, and Seaside is on the list.

Moreover, it's the next improvement step :)

So the answer is not now, but probably soon :)

If someone aware of Seaside want to join effort, he/she is welcome

Comment: Where is the Spec project page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm nor aware of a current binding of Spec to Seaside. A lot of developers use [Magritte](http://code.google.com/p/magritte-metamodel/). There is some work done to render [Glamour](http://www.squeaksource.com/Glamour.html) browsers to Seaside. That's nice, as it allows programming at a very high abstraction level. And for a different approach you might take a look at [Deltawerken](http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/Deltawerken.html) and its [announcement](http://forum.world.st/Ann-Deltawerken-amp-Storyboard-td4646138.html) and [getting started](http://forum.world.st/How-to-approach-building-a-Deltawerken-application-Part-1-tt4647416.html)